# Having a really difficult time understand Promise chaining

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise, chain

**(I think I learned this, it is that .then returns a promise even if it is not run, i never knew this, thank you)**

Please forgive me if this is a dumb question but I simply don't get this, I've googled this many times but those articles only talk about Promise very briefly like how to create one, how to resolve, how to .then and stuff.

I'm confused about promise chaining.

This is my code:

```
    let p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
    
    let value = 19;
    
    if(!value){
        resolve(value)
    } else {
        reject(value)
    }
})

p.then(x => {console.log(x*x); throw false})
    .then(null, x => console.log(x))
//19
```

This code prints 19 and I have no clue why?.

I do know every .then returns a promise but in this case, p.then shouldn't have even run because the promise is not resolved. Now in a way, it seems that didnt run but if so, why did the second .then run?

Our first .then didn't run, it didnt run any promise whatsoever, so nothing should have displayed.

Now unless 2nd .then is working the same as p.then() which I hope it doesnt because that will only create more confusions, I dont understand why will the 2nd .then run?.

I'm sorry again if my question or english bad but I'm really curious about this.

Answer (score 1):

The `.then` function takes two functions as parameters, one which is called when the Promise resolves and one when it rejects. It returns a new Promise which gets resolved or rejected with whatever value the function which was executed returns (or throws). If no handler was executed, the Promise will just resolve or reject with the same value the Promise `.then` was called on.

In your example the first `.then` call only received one argument, and as the Promise rejects it won't be executed. Therefore the Promise it returns will also reject, and thus the second argument will be executed.

```
 // some examples
 Promise.resolve()
   .then(called, notCalled);

 Promise.reject()
   .then(notCalled, called);

 Promise.resolve(1)
    .then(null, notCalled)
    .then(it => it + 1, notCalled)
    .then(called, notCalled);

 Promise.reject(1)
   .then(notCalled, null)
   .then(notCalled, it => it + 1)
   .then(called, notCalled);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for your reply, so the .then/.catch will return the promise even if its not run? 

As you said, I'm only pushing one argument in the p.then which should be run if the promise resolves, in my case, its rejected, so this shoulnt have run.

Or is it what i said, .then will return promise even if it doesnt run?

Comment: Yes, `.then` always returns a new Promise.

Comment: I never knew that even if .then is not run, it still returns a promise. Thanks a ton for that. I read so many articles and all of them only talked promise briefly.

Comment: @imheretolearn1 `.then()` always returns a promise, and does that *before* the callback runs - the callback is always called asynchronously. In most cases, `.then()` returns a promise even before it knows which callback is to be called, as the promise it was invoked on is not yet settled.

Answer (score 0):

A Promise can be in one of these states:

pending -> initial state, neither fulfilled nor rejected.

fulfilled -> the operation was completed successfully.

rejected -> the operation failed.

In your code sample, the promise is being rejected (since if value is a truthy condition).
The then method accepts two arguments:

```
  p.then(onFulfilled[, onRejected]);

  p.then(value => {
     // fulfillment
  }, reason => {
   // rejection
  });
```

Since the then is chainable, the reject get's fired on the second chained then which is the line of code:

```
x => console.log(x)
```

Hence, printing the value 19.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.  

But where am I using 2nd argument here? 

p.then(x => {console.log(x*x); throw false}) 

I'm only using one argument here which should only be run if the promise resolves, since my promise is being rejected, this shouldnt have run?

Comment: In the second then. It is chained to it.

Comment: .then(null, x => console.log(x))

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your questions on the two answers above (and also, perhaps the fact that you didn't selected either answer as correct), I wonder if you're still confused about this.

Here is an explanation based on stepping through your code:

```
p.then(x => {console.log(x*x); throw false})
    .then(null, x => console.log(x))
```

Reading one token at a time:

- p is a promise. It has the code as you defined for p: `let p = new Promise ...`
- We immediately call p's `then` function. This runs the code in p (since p has not yet been run -- promises only run once). Your code in p is a bit confusing because it defines `value` to be 19, but then it says `if ( !value ) ...` which means "if `value` has no value (i.e., is falsey)". In your cause `value` does have a value, 19. So that causes the `else` part to run, which says `reject(value)`. This moves p from an "undetermined" state to a rejected state.
- Back in your main code, the `then` clause (the first one), only has one argument. A `then` clause typically has two arguments, one for code to run if the promise resolves (succeeds), and one if it fails. In your case you only provided one argument to your first `then` call. Since p was rejected, JavaScript doesn't run the code in the first `then`, but (as you point out from your learning in bold) it does still return another promise.
- Now that the promise from the first `then` has been determined, we invoke the chained (second) `then`. Jonas Wilms points out the key fact: *If no handler was executed, the Promise will just resolve or reject with the same value the Promise .then was called on.* So that means the second `then` gets the same result as the first `then`, rejected.
- Since the second `then` has two arguments, JavaScript runs the second one (the one for the rejection case), which prints 19.